# Misquoting Linnaeus or correcting him?

Tags: grammar-choice, comparative

I found a [couple](https://books.google.com/books?id=2X0HAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA50&dq=%22quo+nullum+majus+est%22+linnaeus&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-56S_wcDTAhUS84MKHdKrDu8QuwUIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22quo%20nullum%20majus%20est%22%20linnaeus&f=false) [books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ETAVAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22tanto%20igitur%20magis%20nosse%22&pg=PA295#v=onepage&q=%22quo%20nullum%20majus%20est%22&f=false) [that](https://books.google.com/books?id=tQktAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22quo+nullum+majus+est%22+linnaeus&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22quo+nullum+majus+est%22) quote the introduction to the *Systema Naturæ* thus:

> Tanto igitur magis nosse naturam operæ pretium, quo nullum majus est!

Linnaeus [actually wrote](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_Ix0AAAAAQAAJ):

> Tanto igitur magis nosse Naturam operæ pretium, quo nullum **magis** est!

Were they misquoting Linnaeus or correcting him?

This is actually a Latin grammar question. I was googling for this sentence in hope of finding clues for how to parse it. I had originally misunderstood *Tanto igitur magis* as "So much greater, then, …" That is, I had confused the adverb *magis* with the adjective *maius.* Having sorted that out, I see the first *magis* as part of the infinitive clause *magis nosse Naturam,* "to better know Nature". So now I'm thinking that the whole sentence means something like:

> Therefore such a great labor as to better know Nature is worthwhile, indeed nothing is more valuable!

Since the Latin plays on the idiom *operæ pretium est,* it's hard to translate into English without radically rewriting it or losing something. Regardless of how to say it in English, this interpretation makes the second clause compare *nullum* with *pretium* (*quo*'s antecedent is *pretium*)—which seems to call for *maius,* not *magis.*

On the other hand, if *quo*'s antecedent is *operæ,* then the sentence is saying that no labor is greater—which would agree with the emphasis from starting with *Tanto* but still call (I think) for *maius.*

Or…does the choice of *magis* vs. *maius* disambiguate between possible comparisons?

So, how *do* you parse Linnaeus's sentence?

Comment: [Here's an edition with *majus* instead](https://books.google.com/books?id=KKryMF12p7YC&pg=PA1). I suspect this was either an editorial error or emendation... *majus* definitely seems better.

Comment: @brianpck Correcting him, then. :) (Or quoting a later edition.)